# SSRS Subscription Parameter Performance

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that has ~30 parameters. Most of these are query based, and all queries take less that a second to run. However, when trying to create a Subscription from Reports Manager, the page will become unresponsive trying to load all of the parameter options. We have looked into both the report server db and the data source that the report is based upon and nothing is slow or hanging, thus it seems like report manager is just having a hard time with so many parameter options being loaded. Running the report is actually faster than trying to build a subscription, which doesn't make much sense as the queries should be the same.

Are there any settings that can be edited for the report server config files to try to speed up this performance? We are running SSRS 2016.

Comment: AFAIK your only options are to tune your queries. There seems to be some facility to view what is happening on the server https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2328/sql-server-reporting-services-reports-performance-debugging-and-analysis/

Comment: In general report parameters run their queries the first time you open a report and refresh each time a parameters value change (even report parameters are not related queries)